# Laravel 5.3 : Passport Implementation - {"error":"invalid_client","message":"Client authentication failed"}

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, laravel-5.3, laravel-passport

I followed the exact steps mentioned in the [Laracast : What's New in Laravel 5.3: Laravel Passport](https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-3/episodes/13) to implement `api authentication` using `oauth2`.

My `web.php` file in the client/consumer project looks like:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


Route::get('/', function () {
$query = http_build_query([
     'client_id' => 2,
     'redirect_uri' => 'http://offline.xyz.com/callback',
     'response_type' => 'code',
     'scope' => '',
    ]);

return redirect ('http://api.xyz.com/oauth/authorize?'.$query);
});

Route::get('/callback', function (Request $request){
$http= new GuzzleHttp\Client;

$response = $http->post('http://api.xyz.com/oauth/token',[
    'form_params' => [
            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
            'client_id' => 2 , 
            'client_secret' => 'tUGYrNeWCGAQt220n88CGoXVu7TRDyZ20fxAlFcL' ,
            'redirect_uri' => 'http://offline.xyz.com/callback',
            'code' => $request->code,
        ],
    ]);

return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
});
```

I am getting the permission request page where I need to `authorize` to allow my client to access the api. But, once I click authorize, I am being redirected to the page where it shows the following message:

```
{"error":"invalid_client","message":"Client authentication failed"}
```

How to resolve this?

I did not install `laravel/passport` in the offline project.
Am I missing out something? I have followed and implemented what exactly was mentioned in the video tutorial. Do I have to include something else that I'm not aware of? (I have a very basic knowledge on oauth2).

If it helps, I am trying to implement an offline system which will periodically send data to an online system when there is an internet connection. So I thought I can build an `api` and send `post` request with information to be stored.

Comment: Are you sure your client_id is 2? I didn't watch the tutorial, but usually the oauth client_ids are not the auto increment values in db.

Comment: I have implemented the `vue` components as well and there I can see the list of clients I have with their ids. And with that, I am sure I have a client with id = 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was the `Redirect URL` which I have mentioned while creating the `OAuth Client` was *different* from what I needed. Following the tutorial, I had mentioned `http://api.xyz.com/callback` which **should** have been `http://offline.xyz.com/callback`.

If you have implemented the `vue` components, use the `Edit` option for the `Oauth Client` created. Change the Redirect URL appropriately.

Also, make sure the `id` field and the `redirect` field in the `oauth-clients` table contains the same values as mentioned in the route description for `/callback` in your `routes/web.php` file.

This should fix the error. However, it might raise another error  - `HttpFoundationFactory` not found.

In `composer.json`, update the file with the following in the `require`section:

```
"symfony/psr-http-message-bridge": "0.2"
```

and run `composer update`.

You are good to go now.

Comment: You need to specify which Grant Type your attempting to implement. This fix is specific to ONLY the authorization_code Grant type and hints more towards a setup issue.

Comment: changing the redirect_url fixed it for me

Comment: What do you mean with "If you have implemented the vue components, use the Edit option for the Oauth Client created. Change the Redirect URL appropriately." I have the problem where Vue redirects me, but the URL is not updating, and all is inside a weird box 

Comment: @carlos I meant the UI that Laravel ships with to create and manage oauth clients. They are vue components.

Answer (score 2):

May be you're reinstall your Laravel project or reinstall the passport?
Check that your `client_id` and `client_secret` are the same in all places: ".env" file, "oauth_clients" database table, and in your part of code:

```
   'client_id' => ....,
   'client-secret' => ......
```

In case if it's a different then copy and paste `client_id` and `client_secret` from the "oauth_clients" datatbase table to your code for appropriate parameters (client_id, client_secret).