# Laravel Passport Password Grant - Client authentication failed

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, laravel-5.3

After hearing a lot about laravel passport, i thought of implementing it into my new project where my requirement is to create an API that'll be used in a mobile app.

So my mobile app is a `client`, which will further have its users.

I followed the steps [mentioned by Taylor](https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-3/episodes/13) and also read about it [here](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/introducing-laravel-passport). In a nutshell I followed these steps:

1. Installed `laravel/passport`.
2. Created a website user.
3. Generated passport keys `php artisan passport:install`
4. Generated `client_id` and `client_secret` using `php artisan passport:client`
5. Added `redirection` and `callback` routes in `web.php`
6. Authorized the user and got the final access token.

Then I tried calling `api/user`( with Header `Authorization` containing value `Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1...(token)`

I received the data. Pretty simple and neat.

But my app users won't have these details. So I thought of configuring [Password Grant Tokens](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport#password-grant-tokens) which fits perfectly in my requirement.

Now starts the real headache. I've been trying to set this up for the last 3 days and continuously getting

```
{"error":"invalid_client","message":"Client authentication failed"}
```

I've tried almost every guide I followed online: [Redirection Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39315803/laravel-5-3-passport-implementation-errorinvalid-client-messagecli), [Add Atleast One Scope Solution](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-passport-and-postman-gets-all-the-time-unauthorised), [P100Y Issue](https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/47) etc.

But I'm still getting `invalid client` error. Here's what I'm passing through POSTMAN to `oauth/token`:

```
{
    "grant_type": "password,"
    "client_id": "3,"
    "client_secret": "8BUPCSyYEdsgtZFnD6bFG6eg7MKuuKJHLsdW0k6g,"
    "username": "test@gmail.com,"
    "password": "123456,"
    "scope": ""
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try scope: "*" Honestly ive been stuck on the same thing for the past day as well...

Comment: Yes, i did. Same result

Comment: hate stating the obvious, but looks like your object is not a valid JSON, check your commas

Comment: Did you post the data as form-data within the body tab in Postman? Don't use the Params section.

Comment: After running this command ```php artisan passport:install --force``` in my project root folder, I updated .env ```PASSPORT_CLIENT_ID and PASSPORT_CLIENT_SECRET``` with new ```Password grant client created successfully.
Client ID: 2
Client secret: mn0481KyBQU7cBWJHPj9vp0eSt4G4bGJC0lldBoN```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Check your credentials first if they are correct, Secondly check your model table which uses `\Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens` trait that whether it contains `email` column, because by default it is used to identify user when validating credentials. if your table has `username` column or any other column which is used in validating credentials you must define a function `findForPassport` in that model. like this,

```
public function findForPassport($username) {
       return self::where('username', $username)->first(); // change column name whatever you use in credentials
    }
```

I use username and password column to validate a user,
in `{project_directory}\vendor\laravel\passport\src\Bridge\UserRepository.php`

this function validates your credentials,

```
public function getUserEntityByUserCredentials($username, $password, $grantType, ClientEntityInterface $clientEntity)
    {
        if (is_null($model = config('auth.providers.users.model'))) {
            throw new RuntimeException('Unable to determine user model from configuration.');
        }

        if (method_exists($model, 'findForPassport')) { // if you define the method in that model it will grab it from there other wise use email as key 
            $user = (new $model)->findForPassport($username);
        } else {
            $user = (new $model)->where('email', $username)->first();
        }

        if (! $user || ! $this->hasher->check($password, $user->password)) {
            return;
        }

        return new User($user->getAuthIdentifier());
    }
```

notice the second if statement and you will get to know what  is happening there.

hope this help :)

Comment: I'm not using username.

Comment: Are you sure the client_id you are passing is a password grant client ? i.e password_client column has value 1 in oauth_clients table.

Comment: For me, the `password_client` column value for that particular client was `0`. i manually changed it to `1` but it didn't help.

Comment: set Expiration => Passport::tokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addDays(15));

and second create a virtual host to try on, and don't try with artisan serve command.

Comment: I use ```php artisan passport:client``` but it insert password_client = 0, when I change it to 1, it's work! I don't know why? Any explain why command below insert 0 instead 1.

Comment: `php artisan passport:client --password` run this.

Answer (score 19):

This might help point you in the right direction because we're implementing the password grant ourselves.

1 - On your step 4 instead of running this:

```
php artisan passport:install
```

run the following to create your password grant Client:

```
php artisan passport:client --password
```

The above command will give a followup question to set the name of your Password Grant Client. Be sure to get the id and secret of this new record in your database.

2 - Your POSTMAN Post request object should be wrapped inside an object similar to the following:

```
'form_params' => [
    'grant_type' => 'password',
    'client_id' => 'my_client-id',
    'client_secret' => 'my_client-secret',
    'username' => 'username or email', <-pass through variables or something
    'password' => 'my-user-password', <- pass through variables or something
    'scope' => '',
],
```

**Update 1 10/12/2016:**

On further investigation of this issue I ran into the exact same spot you're at and was forced to dive into the rabbit hole of passport.

Currently from what I'm seeing the system has set the client identifier as 'authorization_code' when it needs to be 'password'. I'm researching how to resolve this issue you're having as I've ran into it too. I will post code to help people follow along where I've been and what I've been doing but it's 2:40 am right now so I need some sleep.

**Update 2 10/12/2016**

Been debugging the issue for 7 hours now. There is a method within passport that validates the client. This method takes the inputs you've added in the object (mentioned above) and attempts to get the Client Entity through a client repository class based on what you've passed in. If a Client is found it will then be checked to see if an instance of the Client Entity truly exists within the Client Entity Interface which LOOKS like it pulls in the Client's credentials from the database. However, there is a block of code which returns NULL From what I'm getting in my testing. ALL fields are being introduced properly so far but there seems to be a mix-up between the repository and the interface. Which is causing the error to be thrown.

In the end I feel I'm getting close to solving this issue. Your patience is greatly appreciated. =)

**Update 3 10/12/2016**

After a long period of debugging I've found the initial problem. There were fields that weren't matching up. In short, it's a setup issue.

SO

The solution in this case is:

**DOUBLE CHECK ALL FIELDS In the database** with **ALL** credentials being passed in. Right down to periods, dashes, spaces passwords, client id, client secret, VALID redirect URIs/URLs, grant_types, and scopes (if you're using them):

Make sure the client in the database has an ENUM of 1 under the "password_client" column, if not you need to create one using the mentioned php artisan command above, which I'll reference here:

```
php artisan passport:client --password
```

Make sure the secret you're passing in matches what is listed for that client in your database character for character

Make sure the id you're passing matches and is of an integer data type.

Make sure there is a name of some sort for the client

Do not worry about the user_id column when using password grants

make sure the route is correct

Make sure the email your entering in (username) is an actual user inside of your users table within your database (or whatever table you customized the laravel 5.3 system to accept as your users table, I will add a link on how to customize laravel 5.3 system to accept a different users table as default if any need it).

Make sure the grant_type is spelled correctly

Make sure you're set up to accept the response bearer token (meaning the access_token and refresh_token).

Other than that, the initial steps I've outlined in the above part of this Answer should put you back on the right track. There are others here who did mention some similar steps that are helpful but address the same error that is related to a seperate issue as well (which I'm sure is a result of a setup issue related to their specific system setup).

I hope this helps though.

Comment: Yes, a bunch of people are facing this issue. Let me know if you find a solution

Comment: Where are you getting stuck at?

Answer (score 8):

Have yo try running `php artisan config:cache` after all the passport commands.

Answer (score 4):

use the below code to generate an access token, it has worked for me before:

```
$request->request->add([
      'client_id' => '2',
      'client_secret' => 'm3KtgNAKxq6Cm1WC6cDAXwR0nj3uPMxoRn3Ifr8L',
      'grant_type' => 'password',
      'username' => 'support@eliteride.co.uk',
      'password' => 'pass22'
    ]);
    $tokenRequest = $request->create('/oauth/token', 'POST', $request->all());

    $token =  \Route::dispatch($tokenRequest);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
{"error":"invalid_client","message":"Client authentication failed"}
```

means that the client_id and client_secret you're currently sending is one of the following:

1. client_id and client_secret being sent is **not registered** in your oauth server
2. client_id and client_secret being sent is **not of the grant type** that you specify in the post body

> For me, the password_client column value for that particular client
>   was 0. i manually changed it to 1 but it didn't help. – Kanav Oct 4 at
>   3:25

As I read your comment to some of the answer makes this one is obvious that you use the wrong type of client_id and client_secret for your password grant flow, so your case was the latter. You can verify that by finding the entry in oauth_clients table for your supplied client_id and client_secret

```
"grant_type": "password,"    
"client_id": "3,"
"client_secret": "8BUPCSyYEdsgtZFnD6bFG6eg7MKuuKJHLsdW0k6g,"

SELECT * FROM oauth_clients WHERE id = 3 AND secret = '8BUPCSyYEdsgtZFnD6bFG6eg7MKuuKJHLsdW0k6g' AND password_client=1;
```

in your oauth_clients table to check that whether your supplied client_id and client_secret **exists for password grant flow** in your oauth server. And also you don't manually change the type of client by simply switching the value of that column, you have to **create a new client** for password grant type.

```
php artisan migrate
```

This command will migrate the laravel/passport migration file to generate two default clients for each type that laravel/passport currently supported. You can also create a client for password grant flow with

```
php artisan passport:client --password
```

When you have a new client for password grant type, try POSTing again to /oauth/token to generate a token with your new generated client_id and client_secret

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are not trying to obtain a token with a hashed `client_secret`...
If you are hashing the client secrets with `Passport::hashClientSecrets();` within `AppServiceProvider`, the tokens generated will only be shown in the terminal output *once*. Loose this token and it is lost forever.

I was in a rush when I set my passport up and forgot that I was hashing the generated client secrets...

My request body should have contained a **non**-encrypted client secret, but instead I copied and pasted an encrypted secret from the database.

To fix this, either save your client secrets right away, or remove `Passport::hashClientSecrets();` and create a *new* client.

Comment: This was my issue, I searched so hard on this x)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and got fixed by setting basic.auth headers, with client_id as username and secret as password.

Then it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Check thoroughly the Grant Type.

```
{
    "grant_type": "password",
    "client_id": 2,
    "client_secret": 
    "username": ,
    "password": 
    "scope": ""
}
```

In the above example, it says password. Now check the table: **oauth_clients**
and make sure that the value of column `password_client = 1`

or look for the entry with the `password_client = 1`

Comment: I had PHPUnit tests failing after laravel and passport upgrades. This seemed to be the issue as changing this `$passwordClient = factory(Laravel\Passport\Client::class, 'passwordClient')->create();` to this ` $passwordClient = factory(Laravel\Passport\Client::class, 'passwordClient')->create(['password_client' => true]);` Fixed this error for me and got my tests passing. It must be something different after the upgrade since the old way used to work.

Answer (score 1):

Try commenting out this line `Passport::hashClientSecrets();` in the `AppServiceProvider` file. You cant use hashed client secrets.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get the Laravel Passport - Password_Grant_Token working through RESTED(POSTMAN like service) without any additional controllers or middlewares. Here is how I've managed to do it!

Install the default Auth-Scaffolding in laravel [doc's here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication)
Install the passport [doc's here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport)
Register a user through auth-scaffolding
Goto RESTED or POSTMAN, or any other like service
Check data in oauth_clients table for your form_params
With RESTED through Request_body_form_data not headers write yours forms_params and send a POST request to */oauth/token (full url required)
(required form_params are grant_type, client_id, client_secret, username and password)

You should get in return an object with 4 keys (token_type, expires_in, access_token & refresh_token) and a status of 200 OK.

If all was succesfull so far...

Open another RESTED window:

Send a GET request to /api/user (again full url required)
In headers write 2 name-value pairs (Accept => application/json, Authorization => Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN_GOTTEN_IN_PREVIOUS_REQUEST (to /oauth/token)

And that should be it. You should get an user object as response from /api/user.

Comment: I've tried sending it both ways: `form-data` and `x-www-form-encoded`. Got the same result

Comment: If you are using POSTMAN select  Oauth 2.0 method under the Authorization Tab. The dialog will ask you for the client password info.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new password client using  php artisan passport:client --password
then most probably an user wont be assigned to that password client. edit the database row and add an exsting user id to it.

```
{
    "grant_type": "password,"
    "client_id": "" <- edited and added user id
    "client_secret": "8BU......," <- new secret
    "username": "test@gmail.com," <- email of above added user id
    "password": "123456,"<- password 
    "scope": ""
}
```

Hope you will be able to get token now

Comment: I've tried what you've suggested and the result is still the same. =/

Answer (score 0):

Check the redirect/callback url when the client is set up on the passport server. Check the entry where you get the client ID and secret from that the Redirect URL is correct.

I was getting the same error and found the Redirect URL wasn't correct.

It needs to be pointing to the /callback route (in the examples that Taylor gives)

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue , i got the solution from this link. Please check that.
https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/71

It says that : 
You make a call to /oauth/token just like you always would to get your token. But do so with a grant_type of custom_request. You'll need to add a **byPassportCustomRequest($request)** method to your **User model** (or whatever model you have configured to work with Passport). That method will accept a Illuminate\Http\Request and return the user model if you are able to authenticate the user via the request, or it will return null.

Answer (score 0):

if you tried everything and still it's not working means try this solution!!
just give  scope  *.

```
$query = http_build_query([
    'client_id' => 1,
    'redirect_uri' => 'http://localhost:3000/callback',
    'response_type' => 'code',
    'scope' => '*'
]);
```

in my case this is the solution. I have checked

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. When you execute `php artisan passport:install` it issues you with two types of secrets, one for CLIENT grant type, and other for PASSWORD grant type.

I was using the CLIENT secret to issue PASSWORD tokens. Once I changed that up, I was able to generate the `access_token` and `refresh_token` normally.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the solution was to wrap it inside Form-data, 
don't miss it out if you use normal parameters with the postman, it won't work,
make sure to use a body request set to FORM-DATA.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will save someone the hour I spent debugging this problem:

I went down the rabbit hole to find out why authentication wasn't working. Turned out I was hashing my password in my UsersTableSeeder twice by accident, which is why the hash check failed.

Might be worth checking if the other answers listed don't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by making sure that in the oauth_clients table my client has column password_client set to 1:

Source: https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/589#issuecomment-357515110

> There may be quite scenarios for the above issue.I will explain it one
> by one. You always need to pass application/json header .
>
> 1. Make sure the client id and secret is in the oauth_clients and you
>    passed those parameter correctly.In order to generate those client id
>    and secret use php artisan passport:install.
> 2. Make sure to use password
>    grant client . To identify that goto oauth_clients table and check if
>    password_client is set to 1 and personal_access_client is set to 0 and
>    revoked to 0 . I hope this will solve the issue . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In `laravel 9.x`, the error : `Client authentication failed` will also be thrown if you have `Passport::hashClientSecrets()` in your `AuthServiceProvider boot` method. Am not sure why, but removing it just saved me time.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a long shot, but after creating your client keys, make sure to check the `oauths_client` table and verify that the  values for `PASSPORT_PERSONAL_ACCESS_CLIENT_ID` and
`PASSPORT_PERSONAL_ACCESS_CLIENT_SECRET` in the .env file match the `user_id` and the `secret` in the database table. Do not use the `id`.

Answer (score -1):

I was having this same issue, I tried all the above solutions, no success.

So i just reloaded the tables, recreated the user, the passport client and solved. My solution was reset everything:

`php artisan migrate:fresh` (will clean your database.)

`php artisan passport:client --password`

Comment: Be careful with the `fresh` because it will erase you data

Answer (score -2):

you can define a two variables like

```
$client_id = '111';
$client_secret = '1212';
```

and the condition is in your function like this

```
protected $clientID = '578324956347895';
protected $clinetSecret ='hflieryt478';

public function index(Request $request)
{

    if (!($request->input('clientID') && $request->input('clinetSecret'))) {
        return false;
    }

    $project = User::all();

   return $project
}
```