# Laravel Passport basic api auth returns "error":"invalid_client","message":"Client authentication failed"

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

### The Problem

I've been trying to use Laravel Passport and I'm countinously getting the error {"error":"invalid_client","message":"Client authentication failed"}. I have used it in this [Android and Laravel](https://github.com/ProgrammationAndroid/Laravel-Passport-Android) project but I just can register the user correctly as I see the proper data in the database. Then when the Android app tries to get the access token it crashes because the server return the previous error message.

I have also been following this [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=loQ4M9qfBtU&index=4&list=PL_2A_Av1AZkhlcH6paF-aHw_FfvCKpDeS) exactly as it is explained but I got this error at the part it sends the "access token request".

**Postman data**
[image: Postman data]

**oauth_clients table**
[image: Database data]

---

### What I have tried

I have tried to fix this using this [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39572957/laravel-passport-password-grant-client-authentication-failed#) page, this [GitHub](https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/221) and many other webpages page but nothing worked

### Possible cause

- I think that it might be the uncompatibility of my laravel version
  and passport (see below). I have manually changed laravel version to 5.4 but I 
  got a composer error. I don't want to reinstall laravel because i think I 
  could crash all my laravel projects.
- The 'user_id' column has to be populated by laravel (I have manually
  changed it to the user_id of the user and after that I restored it to
  zero)
  [image: composer.json]

---

> How to print data to the console? I use error_log() but I can't print variable names and with dd()I get and error saying that the variable couldn't be converted to string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have ever tried configurations like this:? 
client_id and "client_secret" instead client_password.
Your data in param it's the same one that you posted on print "oauth_clients table", right, but I think so your problem is this param "client_password", I never ever seen before this way!

Comment: Problem solved!!! I can deduce that maybe the 'client_password' field was substituted by 'client_secret' in the latest versions. Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

1. you have to wrong pass client_id and client_password
2. if you have to right pass client_id and client_password then check in the database table oauth_clients client_id and client_password is row inserted or not if not added then run this command in console

php artisan passport:client

this will register client_id and client_password and then check that in this table(oauth_clients) if not added then maunally added client_id and client_passsword

Comment: Your answer is not understandable and illogical. Why would I have to pass wrong data? The picture of the database table is of the oauth_clients table. Finally, use proper punctuation marks and correct verb tenses.

Comment: your error say { "error":"invalid_client","message":"Client authentication failed"} which you have client_id and client_password send(pass) this is wrong or not exists in the database...... so you have to send(pass) right client_id and client_password  .... your user detail is right ... (my english is so weak )