# Laravel Passport; using OAuth2 for SSO with Freshdesk

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport, freshdesk

I am trying to set up SSO from my Laravel 8.13 site to my related Freshdesk support portal.

What I want is for a user, who is logged into my site, then to be able to click a button and get seamlessly signed into my Freshdesk support portal so they can view the non-public documentation there and raise tickets if required.

Using Laravel Passport 10.1 I can create a token (tested using Postman) but get an error from Freshdesk when trying to authenticate.

```
An error occurred while attempting to retrieve the userinfo resource: could not extract response: no 
suitable httpmessageconverter found for response type [java.util.map<java.lang.string, 
java.lang.object>] and content type [text/html;charset=utf-8]
```

I have not used OAuth before and am having issues. It may of course be that my understanding of OAuth is just completely wrong but I am finding available documentation on Laravel Passport / Freshdesk OAuth connectivity hard to come by.

I have been through as many related SO questions as I have found but nothing so far seems to exactly fit my issue.

I have also got open tickets with Freshdesk and have had an online support session with a Freshdesk support member but they told me the issue was on my side and they couldn't help further.

I would have thought the client type to use was a Personal Access Client but I have tried that as well as a Password Grant Client and get the same message (as above) for both client types.

As far as the "User info URL*" field on Freshdesk goes,

[image: Userinfo URL field]

I have tried

```
http://testsite.ngrok.io/oauth/tokens
and
http://testsite.ngrok.io/oauth/personal-access-tokens
and 
http://testsite.ngrok.io/api/user
```

But no luck - same message regarding not finding userinfo resource as above.

If I browse directly to

```
http://testsite.ngrok.io/oauth/personal-access-tokens
```

I get the following returned:

```
[{"id":"e595f342722c1045e061f2f026fa7f07181b3d5c69016e9999c5640f1e65928ff6fe2621565ff666c5",
"user_id":43128,"client_id":7,"name":null,"scopes":"openid","email","profile"],"revoked":false,
"created_at":"2021-01-26 10:16:12","updated_at":"2021-01-26 10:16:12", 
"expires_at":"2022-01-26T10:16:12.000000Z","client": 
{"id":7,"user_id":null,"name":"freshworksPersonalAccessClient",
"provider":null,
"redirect":"https:\/\/testsite.freshworks.com\/sp\/OAUTH\/27402945223480041\/callback",
"personal_access_client":true,"password_client":false,"revoked":false,
"created_at":"2021-01-19T23:19:39.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-01-19T23:19:39.000000Z"}}]
```

so something is returned but I am not sure if that is in any way near what Freshdesk is looking for. The support documentation for [Freshdesk](https://support.freshworks.com/support/solutions/articles/238672) states :

[image]

But I do not know where to create that info or in what format it needs to be sent to Freshdesk.

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39572957/laravel-passport-password-grant-client-authentication-failed) and believe that (even though it is for older versions) there might be something in the code for "getUserEntityByUserCredentials" in the UserRepository.php file but I have put logger calls in that function and it doesn't seem to be called.

Any assistance would be absolutely great. If any further information is required please let me know.

*Although I would prefer to keep it within the Laravel ecosystem, I am also open to any other way to set up SSO to Freshdesk without using a third party Identity Provider like ADFS, OneLogin, Okta, Azure and suchlike. I just need to get this done.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. Basically my issue was the format and content returned by the User info URL.

I set up a route  for

/userinfo

to a function in a TestController. In that function I decoded the Bearer token to get the user_id and then used that to retrieve the user details.

Then I created an array and response as below:

```
$thisDecodedUser = User::query()->findOrFail($thisDecodedUserId);

if ($thisDecodedUser) {
    $thisDecodedUserFirstName = $thisDecodedUser->first_name;
    $thisDecodedUserLastName = $thisDecodedUser->last_name;
    $thisDecodedUserEmail = $thisDecodedUser->email;
}


$user_info = array();
$user_info['sub'] = "$thisDecodedUserId";
$user_info['id'] = "$thisDecodedUserId";
$user_info['email'] = "$thisDecodedUserEmail";
$user_info['.id'] = "$thisDecodedUserId";
$user_info['.email'] = "$thisDecodedUserEmail";
$user_info['email_verified'] = "true";

return response(json_encode($user_info))
            ->withHeaders([
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            ]);
```

The code needs refactoring but at least it works for now.

Comment: /userinfo is that route in api.php or web.php and is it a post method?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for pointing me in the right direction in this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/65929987/920598

Even if the array you use contains unused keys.

Actually, the available fields and their format are described here https://support.freshdesk.com/en/support/solutions/articles/50000002088-configuring-custom-sso-policies-under-org

For example, if you want to sync the firstname, the lastname and the language, here's the keys you need to set :

```
<?php
$user_info = [
    'sub' => (string)$user->id,
    'unique_id' => (string)$user->id,
    'email' => $user->email,
    'FirstName' => (string)$user->firstname,
    'LastName' => (string)$user->lastname,
    'language' => $user->default_ln === 1 ? 'fr' : 'en'
];
```